# ошибка __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1

Tags: c++, arm

Во время линковки проекта происходит ошибка:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Tld/stm32f10x.ld -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 \
-Wmisleading-indentation -nostdlib build/main.o \
build/src/asm/gcc_ride7/startup_stm32f10x_hd.o \
build/src/system_stm32/system_stm32f10x.o  -o build/program.elf

build/main.o:(.ARM.exidx+0x8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1'
```

Поиск в гугле результатов не дал. Проблемма возникает при обращении к функции объекта через указатель: obj->function();

Подскажите, как избавиться от __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1?

Comment: Псмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210812/what-is-aeabi-unwind-cpp-pr1-and-how-can-i-avoid-it), не поможет?

Comment: Проект на С++, а компилируете вы, небось, gcc вместо g++? Да и наличие флага `-nostdlib` как бы уже гарантирует, что полезут такие проблемы и их надо будет решать по одной. Разбирайтесь, где у вас находится `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1` и линкуйте соответствующий объектник.

Comment: @Ant, в вопросе явно указан `gcc`. А наличие опции `-nostdlib` не гарантирует проблем.

Comment: @0andriy: "Гарантирует" или "не гарантирует" - вопрос праздный. В данном случае мы отчетливо наблюдаем именно эти проблемы. Более того, по списку объектных файлов группы `stm32f10x` в командой строке видно, что аффтар уже начал решать эти проблемы. Но почему-то недорешал.

Comment: Потому что ему ещё надо `libgcc` подключать, как я думаю.

Comment: Да, согласно интернету, `aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1` сидит в `libgcc`. Но они, как я понимаю, как раз таки стараются избежать прямого подключения `libgcc`.

Comment: libgcc пробовал подключать, положительного результата не получил. @Flowneee, да так получилается. Кто знает что это за функция, какова ее роль?

Comment: @АлександрТройнин не могу точно сказать, но по названию похоже на что-то ответственное за обработку исключений

Answer (score 0):

Cудя по всему функция [__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/386ddae58459341ec567604707805814a2128a57/lib/libc/arm/aeabi/aeabi_unwind_cpp.c)  используется для вызова функции [abort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/abort) которая аварийно завершает программу. Скорей всего аналогичным образом используется и в embedded systems.